# Are probability mass functions instances of probability density functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say we have the probability space $(\{H,T\},2^{\{H,T\}},P)$ for
$$
P : x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
p & \text{ if } x=H,\\
(1-p) & \text{ if } x=T
\end{cases}
$$
together with the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. A common random variable between these spaces is
$$X:\{H,T\}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } x=H,\\
0 \text{ if } x=T.
\end{cases}
$$

With respect to the measure

$$\delta:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty]:A\mapsto
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } 0,1\notin A,\\
1 \text{ if } 0\in A \text{ xor } 1\in A,\\
2 \text{ if } 0,1\in A
\end{cases}$$
the probability *density* function of $X$ is given by
$$f_X = (1-p)1_{\{0\}} + p1_{\{1\}}$$
as
$$\int_Af_X\text{d}\delta = (1-p)\delta(\{0\}\cap A)+p\delta(\{1\}\cap A) = P(X\in A).$$

So $f_X$ is what would commonly be called the probability mass function of $X$.

---

So, as the example above illustrates, are probability mass functions instances of probability density functions with respect to appropriate measures $\delta$?

Comment: Apart from the nomenclature. I find it quite odd to speak in case of a discrete distribution of probability density. When you modify it to
$$
f_X=(1-p)1_{(-\infty,1/2)}+p1_{[1/2,+\infty)}
$$
this will be another density of the distribution w.r.t. $d\delta\,.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can use the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) instead of $\delta$.

Yes, if your concept of a probability density function is general enough to be "with respect to a measure", then a probability mass function is nothing more than a probability density function with respect to the counting measure.

Wikipedia says as much in the [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Discussion) article:

> The probability mass function of a discrete random variable is the density with respect to the counting measure over the sample space.

and in the [Probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Measure_theoretic_formulation) article:

> A probability mass function of a discrete random variable ${\displaystyle X}$ can be seen as a special case of two more general measure theoretic constructions: the distribution of
> ${\displaystyle X}$ and the probability density function of
> ${\displaystyle X}$ with respect to the counting measure.